# Changing the topic of list of listings

Tags: listings, lists

I'm using the package `listings` for the code snippets in my document. But I want them to be named "Code" rather than "listings". I already got that in my document, but when I create a `\lstlistoflistings`, it still is titled with "Listings".

How can I change the topic to "Code fragments"? (or anything else?)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code}

\section{foo}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A listing}]
    Some source code
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `\lstlistingname` gives the name of a single listing, the name for the list of listings is given by `\lstlistlistingname`. So just do:

```
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Code fragments}
```